# Integrating gTest Framework in a Custom OS Project in CLion

Tags: c++, c, linux, operating-system, kernel

I was wondering if there is any feasible method / online resources / etc... that could help me with the following problem.

We're writing a custom OS, which is mostly based on the Linux Kernel and following POSIX standard. It's able to run on the x86_64, and it has a well known structure (userspace, archcommon, archmemory, syscall, scheduler, etc...). All of these files are in their own separate subfolders and they contain CMakeLists.txt's.

The root directory contains a huge CMakeLists.txt which binds them all, compiles the entire operating system essentially into one single executable file (thanks to GNU).

The OS can then later be run with `cmake /path/to/src`, `make -j` and `make qemu`.

Qemu just simply allows us to interact with the operating system. A terminal console pops up, and we can type in custom written userspace test files, to test the implementations e.g. of certain syscalls such as pthreads, fork, ...

And here comes my question: Is it possible (as this is a pretty huge and complex project) to include a popular google test framework s.a. gTest into the project? And the idea behind this is that whenever `make qemu` is called, and the OS finishes bootup, I want an automatic test runner to run through all the tests (or perhaps only a select few) defined within the userspace. CLion has a really nice and comfy gTest Integration built-in, so it would only make sense to use that given power.

I believe it would drastically improve the QoL with testing out functionalities and generally covering big parts of the codebase. Unfortunately I couldn't find any helpful resources on this matter.

Help would be greatly appreciated, thank you so much in advance :)!

Comment: GoogleTest uses C++ language and requires support of C++11 standard. Does your OS provides it? It yes, then incorporating GoogleTest should be quite simple, just follow the same approach as in "normal" projects.